# PostgreSQL not using index on wildcard

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching

I have a persons table. I want to look them up by using a field `person_code` which is an alphanumeric string. I have created an index as:

```
create index my_idx on persons( some_function(person_code) )
```

However, when I try something like:

```
select * from persons where some_function(person_code) like 'mycode%'
```

I end up having a sequential scan instead of an index scan. According to [Postgres index types documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html), `LIKE` should make use of an index as long as matching pattern is a constant and is anchored to the beginning of the string.

Comment: It will use an index if the planner thinks there's a benefit to using an index.  This depends on number of rows, table stats, how many rows it thinks will be returned, etc.

Comment: Please add the execution plan (using `explain (analyze, verbose)`) as **formatted** text to your question

Comment: `some_function(person_code) like 'mycode%'` What is some_function? Chances are big that the function *cannot* use an index, just because it is a function.

Comment: @wildplasser - Should be able to, if it's marked as IMMUTABLE I believe.  [Details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/xfunc-volatility.html)

Comment: No of course not. Example: MD5 is (probably) immutable. Counter example: left() is immutable, too.

Comment: Oops, I didnt read the text. To the OP could you **please post the table and function definitions** thank you.

Comment: Hmm, strange.  I've put indexes on the lower case version of text before and used an index to search.  `LOWER()` is just an immutable function.

Comment: What your question needs: - Postgres version (*always!*). - Table definition or at least the exact data type of `person_code` ("alphanumeric string" is not a data type). - Verbatim index definition (you are hiding the essential function name). - Function definition, unless it's a built-in Postgres function. - Output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)`. - Cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of your sample query it will be tough to assist you with your problem, but you may take a look at **`pg_trgm`** module [**here**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html). Sample index for `ILIKE/LIKE` operations may be the following:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_persons_person_code_trgm ON person USING gin (person_code gin_trgm_ops);
```

Article worth checking:

- **[Faster LIKE/ILIKE](http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/)**